# how to enable sqlserver connection at my php5.6

Tags: php, sql-server, wordpress, pdo

My environment is Windows10, Apache, PHP5.6, Wordpress.

To connect SQL server by WordPress plugin, I tried using [Medoo libary](https://medoo.in/)

But, I am stuck with the error message below.

### PHP Fatal error:

> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'could not find driver'

#### Here are my trials.

1. Downloaded Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server and copy them to PHP ext folder.
2. Added below lines to `php.ini`

   ```
   extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
   extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
   extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
   extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
   ```
3. Restarted Apache => not fixed.

When I checked PHP info, I found configuration command has `--without-mssql`.

```
cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--disable-isapi" "--enable-debug-pack" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"
```

Is it related to this problem?  If that, how can I download MSSQL enabled PHP version?

**UPDATE**
My PHP didn't load sqlserver module.  How can I check why PHP doesn't load sqlserver mobule?

```
C:\AutoSet9\server\bin>php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
ereg
filter
ftp
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mcrypt
mhash
mysqlnd
odbc
pcre
PDO
Phar
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

Comment: According to Microsoft's documentation, the `extension=foo.dll` should be set only after validating the `extension_dir=` is correct in `php.ini`.  If you're testing using the `php -m` command, changes should be immediate without restarting Apache.  What Microsoft does not mention is which versions are offered in both 32-bit and 64-bit versions.  Testing the PHP 5.5 driver (using the recommended 3.1 or 3.2 version of the driver) doesn't seem to work on Windows 10 64-bit + WAMP64, says "Not a valid win32 application".  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver

Comment: Furthermore, Microsoft makes no specific mention of the `--without-mssql` build flag.  It is present in a default WAMP64 installation as well.

Comment: @QZSupport you're right.  problem might be the 32-bit and 64-bit versions.   thank your advice.

Comment: Try to use the same binary version of apache, php (e.g. both are vc14 and win32)

Comment: `mssql` library is not the same as `sqlsrv` library. `mssql` is discontinued (http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php). So the `--without-mssql` flag is not your problem. The `sqlsrv` library has to be installed and configured though. It's often not part of the default install so you may need to download and install it separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official SQL Server driver for PHP is only for 32 bit. and Microsoft 32 bit sqlserver driver doesn't work with my php 5.6 64 bit binary.

So after replacing sqlserver driver to this unoffical version, problem was gone.

Step to fix it.

download from below url. http://robsphp.blogspot.kr/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html
update php.ini to above installed module.